# UIStoryboard Change Tab Bar Button Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am writing program with MainStoryBoard like this. I have UITabBarController with 5 tabs. In viewdidload of each uiviewcontroller, I set like this. But, it will only do if I go to that page. So, I am planning to do in my AppDelegate for all tabs. How shall I do programatically? I can set text in UIStoryBoard but I need to set programmatically.

```
self.title = @"Some title";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this you should get the storyboard instance first. And then get tabbar from story board. Do this in the following method of AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
        UITabBarController *tabBar = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController] ;
        NSLog(@"%@",tabBar.viewControllers);
       // You will get list of your viewcontrollers added to tabbar .Get the instances of those view controllers and set title to them here.
       return YES;
  }
```

Comment: It create me new instance for that storyboard. It is not the instance that app will use because we define our storyboard in the main interface.